# pandas get first row for each unique value in a column

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas data frame, how can I get the first row for each unique value in a column?

for example, given:

```
    a   b   key
0   1   2   1
1   2   3   1
2   3   3   1
3   4   5   2
4   5   6   2
5   6   6   2
6   7   2   1
7   8   2   1
8   9   2   3
```

the result when analyzing by column `key` should be

```
    a   b   key
0   1   2   1
3   4   5   2
8   9   2   3
```

---

p.s. df src:

```
pd.DataFrame([{'a':1,'b':2,'key':1},
 {'a':2,'b':3,'key':1},
 {'a':3,'b':3,'key':1},
 {'a':4,'b':5,'key':2},
 {'a':5,'b':6,'key':2},
 {'a':6,'b':6,'key':2},
 {'a':7,'b':2,'key':1},
 {'a':8,'b':2,'key':1},
 {'a':9,'b':2,'key':3}])
```

Answer (score 3):

`drop_duplicates` does this.  By default it keeps the first of the set, although that can be changed by other parameters.

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('key')
```